# Can I transform the value of my primary key in a specific one-to-many relationship using Fluent API?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to manually scaffold part of an existing database schema in EF Core 2.2. The database in question is part of a 3rd party ERP software, and I have zero control over the design of the database itself, so I'm trying to work with what I am given. So far it's going okay, however I am hitting a snag due to a questionable database design choice by the ERP vendor.

Consider the following one-to-many relationship I'm trying to build in my OnModelCreating() method within my DbContext (via Fluent API):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrderHeader>(s => {
   s.HasMany<WorkOrderHeader>(e => e.WorkOrders)
      .WithOne()
      .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.SalesOrderNumber)
      .HasForeignKey(e => e.RelatedPO_SONumber);
});
```

This is almost what I need, however, in the WorkOrders table "RelatedPO_SONumber" is of type string, where "SalesOrderNumber" in SalesOrderHeaders table is of type int. Further, what's stored in "RelatedPO_SONumber" is a 0-padded string (always 8 characters long) of "SalesOrderNumber" (eg SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNumber = 1234567, WorkOrder.RelatedPO_SONumber = "01234567").

Here's what I tried and might help illustrate what I'm trying to do via format specifier (throws ArgumentException "The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'"):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrderHeader>(s => {
   s.HasMany<WorkOrderHeader>(e => e.WorkOrders)
      .WithOne()
      .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.SalesOrderNumber.ToString("D8"))
      .HasForeignKey(e => e.RelatedPO_SONumber);
});
```

I tried an alternative approach which was to make another property in my SalesOrderHeader entity definition, and using that as the argument for HasPrincipalKey():

```cs
// within SalesOrderHeader
[NotMapped]
public string ZeroPaddedSONumber => SalesOrderNumber.ToString("D8");

// within DbContext OnModelCreating()
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrderHeader>(s => {
   s.HasMany<WorkOrderHeader>(e => e.WorkOrders)
      .WithOne()
      .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.ZeroPaddedSONumber)
      .HasForeignKey(e => e.RelatedPO_SONumber);
});
```

This resulted in:

> "InvalidOperationException: No backing field could be found for property 'ZeroPaddedSONumber' of entity type 'SalesOrderHeader' and the property does not have a setter."

Is there a way to pass anything other than a strict property reference, but rather a transformed "version" of that property?"

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Following a suggestion in a comment, I tried this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrderHeader>(s => {
   s.Property(e => e.SalesOrderNumber)
      .HasConversion(n => n.ToString("D8"), s => int.Parse(s));

   s.HasMany<WorkOrderHeader>(e => e.WorkOrders)
      .WithOne()
      .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.SalesOrderNumber)
      .HasForeignKey(e => e.RelatedPO_SONumber);
});
```

This doesn't seem to work either, I get the following exception (I get the same exception if I omit the conversion):

> The types of the properties specified for the foreign key {'RelatedPO_SONumber'} on entity type 'WorkOrderHeader' do not match the types of the properties in the principal key {'SalesOrderNumber'} on entity type 'SalesOrderHeader'.

Comment: Have you tried `NumberToStringConverter`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#built-in-converters

Comment: @crgolden I had no idea that existed, but it looks like it might work? I will give it a shot however at a glance it looks like it might make that conversion every time. This will not work for me because there are other tables that rely on the int value of SalesOrderNumber for their relationships. If I'm able to get this to work I will post it as an answer (if no one else beats me to it). Thanks, in any case.